# Angular 2: How to add dynamically html attributes (aria-hidden = "true") to all elements directly under the body?

Tags: angular

I have made a custom Modal implementation and want also to ensure accessibility. So when a modal window pops up (modal element is added directly to the document body), all the other elements in body (direct children of body) should have aria-hidden = "true". How can i add this dynamically to all body children?

Answer (score 0):

probably the easiest way would be to mark the parent element, which will in turn mark all children as aria-hidden as well. Something like this:

```
<my-modal></my-modal>
<div class="rest-of-content" aria-hidden="true">
 // All of these will be affected by the aria-hidden of the parent element
   <div>
      .....
   </div>
   <div>
   ....
   </div>
</div>
```

Apart from that, there is no magical way to just mark all other elements as aria-hidden (that I know of). You'll have to implement the logic yourself.

Comment: since the modal component will be used overall dynamically, the parent element can also be 'many'.. other application states should also can add any component anywhere anytime..

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this one. I don't know how bad/good is using document directly within an Angular App, but it works.

I also save those modified elements in arrays, in order to reverse the changes, after modal is closed.

```
  // Add aria-hidden="true" to all direct children of the body element (unless the element does not have already)
  Array.from(document.body.children).forEach(function(item) {
    if(!item.hasAttribute('aria-hidden')) {
      this.elementsWithoutAriaHidden.push(item);
      this.renderer.setAttribute(item, 'aria-hidden', true);
    } else if(item.getAttribute('aria-hidden') === 'false') {
      this.elementsWithAriaHiddenFalse.push(item);
      this.renderer.setAttribute(item, 'aria-hidden', true);
    }
  }, this);
```

*renderer is initialized this way (I have Angular 5):

```
  constructor(private rendererFactory: RendererFactory2) {
    this.renderer = rendererFactory.createRenderer(null, null);
  }
```